# Как с помощью консоли сделать lst файл, masm32?

Tags: ассемблер

знатоки скажите как с помощью консоли сделать lst файл код работает прекрасно но надо знать тонкости в obj компонуется спокойно и в exe но проблема в том что надо не через линк а через link16 тогда работает,

```
.586
.model flat, stdcall

TITLE EX_PROG
PAGE ,123
STACK SEGMENT PARA STACK 'STACK'
DB 64 DUP ('STACK')
STACK ENDS
DSEG SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'DATA'
SOURCE DB 10,20,30,40
DEST DB 4 DUP(?)
DSEG ENDS
SUBTTL 
PAGE 
CSEG SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'CODE'
ASSUME CS:CSEG, DS:DSEG, SS:STACK
OUR_PROG PROC FAR
PUSH DS
SUB AX,AX
PUSH AX
MOV AX,DSEG
MOV DS,AX
MOV DEST,0
MOV DEST+1,0
MOV DEST+2,0
MOV DEST+3,0
MOV AL, SOURCE
MOV DEST+3,AL
MOV AL, SOURCE+1
MOV DEST+2,AL
MOV AL, SOURCE+2
MOV DEST+1,AL
MOV AL, SOURCE+3
MOV DEST,AL
RET
OUR_PROG ENDP
CSEG ENDS
END OUR_PROG
```

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но формат команды TASM [options] source [,object] [,listing] [,xref]
когда вы вводите tasm prog.asm тогда тасм создает только obj-файл, добавление трех запятых приведет к созданию obj-, lst-, xrf-файлы. для генерации лист-файлов используется ключ где TASM /l - /l=normal listing, а TASM /la /la=expanded listing.
В итоге должно получиться, что-то вроде "tasm/prog.asm , , ,"

Comment: а мне нужен масм код сделан на масм